# How to filter a single object when multiple objects are passed through as JSON in Android

Tags: android, listview

[image: Debug Image Sample]

Hi All, I am having  a list view where the values are taken from JSON. My problem is while clicking the item in the listview i need to get exact value that is clicked.Here when i use String str = ListView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(); it gives  (Id="1",Category="xxx"). But i need that category value alone. How can i do that?

My Source:
      lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                            long itemId) {

        String selectedcity = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Intent i = new Intent(CitySelection.this,MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("SelectedCity",selectedcity);
        startActivity(i);

    }
});
```

Comment: You should parse the json in a dto with category and id as attributes, then call dto.getCategory();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse it as a json and extract the data you want, in your case:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
                                long itemId) {

            String myJsonString  = lv.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

            JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myJsonString);
            String selectedcity = json.getString("Category");
            Intent i = new Intent(CitySelection.this,MainActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("SelectedCity",selectedcity);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaythaking. This trick works. Only thing is we have to parse it in try catch block. Otherwise Unhandled exception will occur.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid workink with json as string, instead create objects (DTO's) to represent it. So you have two ways to do it, first one create a JsonObject of your json content:

```
JSONObject j = new JSONObject(json);
json.getString("Category");
```

The second one (and most recommended), create a dto like:

```
CityDto {
    Integer id;
    String category;
    ...
}
```

parse it:

```
CityDto dto = new ObjectMapper().parse(json, CityDto.java);
```

Then, just call dto.getCategory();